# Multiple iif and condition in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I get an error from the below expression in SSRS report. If status is active and month_nbr and year_nbr  is greater than last day of status_DT, it will show count_value which is int type. Can you help me fix it? Thanks!

```
=IIf((fields!status.value="Active") and
(cdate("01"+Fields!month_nbr.Value+Fields!year_nbr.Value)>
DateAdd("d",-1,(DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(fields!Status_DT.value),
Month(fields!Status_DT.value), 1))))),Fields!Notes_Count.Value,"9999")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
cdate("01"+Fields!month_nbr.Value+Fields!year_nbr.Value)
```

by:

```
CDATE(CStr(Fields!year_nbr.Value)+"-"+CStr(Fields!month_nbr.Value)+"-01")
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works. Do you know if want to replace "9999"  to "N/A", how can I change the expression? The Fields!Notes_Count.Value is integer type. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Cindy, If my answer solved your initial issue you can select it as correct answer to notify your issue is solved. Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). For replace "9999" to "N/A" just change this final part from this `Fields!Notes_Count.Value,"9999"` to this `Fields!Notes_Count.Value,"N/A"`.